# Unit testing "authorize" Spring Security JSP taglib

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, taglib

Is there a way to unit test the use of the [authorize tag](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html) provided by Spring Security? The [MockMvc integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc) does not go far enough to do that, as I can only seem to check for the forwarded/redirected URL but not the content of the URL.

The work I am doing involves writing custom SpEL expressions and it would be great to check that they work on real `sec:authorize` usages! Right now I am confined to testing that the basic call to these expressions are working outside the scope of the JSP pages (specifically using the `access` attribute in the `intercept-url` element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, JSPs don't work in unit testing since they need to be compiled by the servlet container. I would recommend using something that works without the container (i.e. [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/)) since you can easily render your response in these instances.

If you use a technology that can render outside of the container, then you can leverage the [HtmlUnit MockMvc integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-mvc-test-server-htmlunit) found in Spring Framework 4.2+. If you are on an older version of Spring Framework and cannot upgrade, you can use [Spring Test HtmlUnit](http://docs.spring.io/spring-test-htmlunit/docs/current/reference/html5/).

**NOTE** Spring Test HtmlUnit is now only maintained as part of Spring Framework 4.2+ and not as a distinct project.

If you really must use JSPs, it will likely be somewhat painful. However, there is a [pretty decent github project](https://github.com/genthaler/jetty-jsp-unit-test-simple) that lists some mechanisms for unit testing JSPs. Out of the options [JspTest](https://github.com/jsptest/jsptest) seems the most promising (but still quite dated).

If you are feeling ambitious it would be quite interesting to see if you could provide a hook with Jasper (Tomcat's JSP compiler) to work with MockMvc.